# url management flow in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, bootstrapping

I have implemented project using Yii framework. URL manager works fine but. i need to change the URL text. it could be shown domain name after the category name. ie my project URL is kitchenking.com. After the domain name my category name should be display.

ie kitchenking.com/Thanksgiving. But my project url display like this i shows follow:

```
http://kitchenking.com/recipe/index1/name/Thanksgiving
```

i did my config file shows following. please suggest me where needs to change the code.

```
'Home'=>'site/index',
            //'cuisine'=>'recipe/index3',

                            'cuisine/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'recipe/index3',
            'holidays/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'recipe/index1',
            'calories/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'recipe/index2',
          'recipeshow/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'recipe/recipeshow',                                
            //'recipeshow'=>'recipe/recipeshow',
            'recipeshow/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'index.php/recipe/course',
```

above code. i wants to be change like this. recipe/index3 instead cuisine, 
recipe/index2 instead holidays,

Answer (score 0):

In UrlManager modify the rules as follows :-

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'rules' => array(
        'cuisine' => 'recipe/index3',
        'holidays' => 'recipe/index3',
    )
)
```